# Index multiple attributes within one key space in Cassandra

Tags: php, cassandra

I am using php library in https://github.com/kallaspriit/Cassandra-PHP-Client-Library/ for Cassandra. 
Although I tried to find answers of my question in Web, I cannot. So, I would like to hear some opinion.

For example, I am thinking of the following structure(i.e. column).

ID, brand, speed

For these three data, I want to do two kinds of operations:
1. get all IDs in Cassandra
2. get all columns by brand name, hopefully by using regex.

So far, I could achieve the first one "1.get all IDs in Cassandra" by creating a super column family called "car".
And, insert a data like the following:

```
cassandra->set(
            $this->columnFamily.'.ID',
            array(
                $id => array(
                    'ID' => $id,
                    'brand' => $brand,
                    'speed' =>$speed
                )
            )
        );
```

Then, I can get all list of IDs by the following code:

```
 cassandra->cf('car')->getAll('ID')
```

When I tried to do the second question, I got stuck.
After searching on the Web, it looks that I need to create another super column family for searching by "brand".
But, the question came out when I found that kind of information.
If we create another super column family with the same structure, I feel it is very memory inefficient. 
Creating another super column family means that Cassandra create another space even if we create the same structure ??
If there is any efficient way to achieve this, could you suggest that?

And, also this is very specific question. getWhere method of this php library can use some condition, e.g. larger than 24 years old?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You're thinking of this in a relational fashion, but Cassandra encourages us to write multiple copies of the data and doesn't support grouping / aggregation or joins.

You may find this useful; "The data model is dead, long live the data model".

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=px6U2n74q3g

Comment: Thanks, I watched a little bit. So, writing the same data in multiple places for the difference purposes is encouraged. So, this indicates if I want to get two kinds of search (in this case, id & brand name), I should create two different column families? Is this an appropriate approach? I still cannot get out of relation mind.

Comment: A classic case of "it depends" :) - do you know the brand when you are searching by ID? If so, you could set up one table with a primary key of (Brand, ID) - the query mechanism will go left to right so you can search by brand, and also brand and ID, based on that single table.